# How to use SOUNDEX dynamically in SQL Server 2008

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, compare, comparison

I have once user search text box in that when somebody is entering name , it should fetch names which is having similar sound.

I have checked SOUNDEX AND DIFFERENCE FUNCTIONS but don't know how to use it dynamically.

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE('DIPAK', 'DEEPAK');  
SELECT SOUNDEX ('DIPAK'), SOUNDEX ('DEEPAK');
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean using different string values within your function, you can just use parameters within your query:

```
declare @Search nvarchar(50) = 'DIPAK';
select soundex(@Search);
```

If you want to compare this to values in a table, you will need to either calculate the `soundex` of your lookup values within your `where` or `join` conditions or add a column to your table that holds this value:

```
declare @SearchSoundex nvarchar(10) = soundex('DIPAK');

select *
from Names
where soundex(FirstName) = @SearchSoundex;
```

---

```
declare @SearchSoundex nvarchar(10) = soundex('DIPAK');

select *
from Names
where FirstNameSoundex = @SearchSoundex;
```

Comment: @imdave But why SOUNDX for POOJA and PIYUSH is same?

Comment: @Shardul  That is something you will need to take up with Microsoft regarding how the `soundex` function works.  There are alternatives such as Metaphone: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=13574  that you will need to implement yourself that may work more to your satisfaction.